# View Neighboring Wi-Fi Networks?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I used to know of a program that would show a graph of the strengths and channels of all the wireless networks within range of my computer, but now I can no longer find it.

Does anyone know of a Windows program that does this?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Whooops forgot to mention, sorry. Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Windows you can use [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) from MetaGeek
(they also have a [linux](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/linux) version but I don't have any experience with it)

Comment: YUP that's the **exact program** I was looking for, thanks a bunch!! That was fast! :)